# Are PHP pthreads the same as the POSIX threads?

Tags: php, pthreads, posix

I found this reference to pthreads in order to do threading in PHP which is new:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

But when I google pthreads only references for POSIX threads come up, which are abbeviated to pthreads.  Are they the same thing?

Comment: Check the link @MarcB. It's new. "pthreads is an Object Orientated API that allows user-land multi-threading in PHP".  Just wanted to know if it is the same as or related to POSIX threads.

Comment: but the PHP pthread is an extension of the POXIS thread, right?

Comment: @MarcB - are you really sure that what you commented is factually truth? Googling on some phrases related to php and threads I stumbled upon this link and what you wrote seems to be incorrect and in direct conflict with what Joe Watkins says. Could you confirm your claims or mark the comment as obsolete to avoid confusion for other visitors?

Answer (score 2):

pthreads is a userland threading API for PHP, based on Posix Threads, supported on windows by pthread-w32.

http://pthreads.org

Comment: + I think more example with the difference would help

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand this PHP extension makes system pthreads (POSIX threads) available to PHP, i.e. a wrapper plus some extra bits and pieces to integrate it into php.

As you can see here, in their source code for the extension, Thread::start() uses the POSIX pthread_create()

In short, the answer to your question is "yes". This is proper POSIX threads in PHP. Examples are on their page: http://pthreads.org/tutorials/start.html
and in the github repo: https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/tree/master/examples